# pytest parametrized fixture - parameters from json?

Tags: python, json, pytest, fixture

Sample code from [pytest.org](https://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html#parametrizing-a-fixture), is it possible to load params from a json file?

```
# content of conftest.py 
import pytest
import smtplib

@pytest.fixture(scope="module",
            params=["smtp.gmail.com", "mail.python.org"])
def smtp(request):
    smtp = smtplib.SMTP(request.param)
    def fin():
        print ("finalizing %s" % smtp)
        smtp.close()
    request.addfinalizer(fin)
    return smtp
```

I would like to do something like

```
# conftest.py
@pytest.fixture(scope="module", params=a_list_var)
def fixture_a(request):

    # some.py or anywhere?
    a_list_var = load_json(parameter_file_path)

    # test_foo.py
    ... 
    def test_foo(fixture_a)
    ...
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Given json file:

```
["smtp.gmail.com", "mail.python.org"]
```

You may simply load it to Python object and pass that object to decorator.

```
import json
import pytest
import smtplib

def load_params_from_json(json_path):
    with open(json_path) as f:
        return json.load(f)

@pytest.fixture(scope="module", params=load_params_from_json('path/to/file.json'))
def smtp(request):
    smtp = smtplib.SMTP(request.param)
    def fin():
        print ("finalizing %s" % smtp)
        smtp.close()
    request.addfinalizer(fin)
    return smtp
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using [pytest-generate-tests] (https://pytest.org/latest/parametrize.html#basic-pytest-generate-tests-example) for this.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks, I ended up using [pytest-generate-tests](https://pytest.org/latest/parametrize.html#basic-pytest-generate-tests-example) for this, my json path will be changed depending on the test case.

```
# test_foo.py
def test_foo(param)

# conftest.py
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    ... my <same_name_as_test>.json
    ... get info from metafunc.module 
    with open(param_full_path,'r') as f:
        obj = json.load(f)
        metafunc.parametrize("param", obj)
```

Comment: would be helpful if an example of using this in a test was shown.